# PHP - is there any way to differentiate between unset and null?

Tags: php

Consider the following code:

```
class Test {
    public $definedButNotSet;
}

$Test = new Test();

var_dump($Test->definedButNotSet=== null); // true
var_dump(isset($Test->definedButNotSet)); // false

$Test->definedButNotSet = null;
var_dump(isset($Test->definedButNotSet)); // false
```

It seems to me, that PHP implicitly sets a defined variable to null. Is there any way to circumvent this, and differentiate between a variable that was explicitly set to `null` and a variable that was only defined, but not set to any value?

**UPDATE**:

What I basically want to see if during the runtime the `definedButNotSet` variable was updated or not. So my expected results for the following code are:

```
$Test = new Test();
var_dump(isset($Test->definedButNotSet)); // false

$Test->definedButNotSet = null;
var_dump(isset($Test->definedButNotSet)); // true expected here but php returns false
```

An actual use case where the difference indeed matters, and basically this would be my use case also: when updating rows in a database, I would like to update the rows of a table, that the user changed only when an update method is called. For this, I have to know, if the user implicitly modified any variable in the class representing the row in the table or not.

I am running a custom ORM, which at the moment, fails, if I insert a row in a database with a column which has a default_timestamp method set as the default value, and in the same runtime, I try to update the same row again, as the database set value is not reflected in my class instance, thus at the update PHP sends to him that his value is null, which is not allowed.

Comment: try this one:
`var_dump($Test->definedButNotSet);`

Comment: @Orhan it still returns the same values....

Comment: Short answer is NO.  The default value will be `NULL` if it has been defined.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/l4faY

Comment: @AbraCadaver it still says that my variable is null for both test cases. I updated my question.

Comment: I know, the DEFAULT value is `NULL` even before you instantiate the object https://3v4l.org/FlrTE that's just how it is.

Comment: @AbraCadaver back to my original question again then, is there ANY way to differentiate between a variable that was implicitly or explicitly set?

Comment: Not unless you track it yourself, no.

Comment: any pointers on how I could track this, while still maintaining intellisense support for an ORM like class object?

Comment: unset completely does delete variable from memory , but the null, set value of the variable as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To challenge the framing of the problem, slightly, what you want to do is distinguish two types of write to the same property: those triggered automatically by your ORM, and those triggered manually by the user. Values which will be provided a default on insert are one subset of that, but values *retrieved* from the database may also need to be handled differently from those provided by the user (e.g. to track if an update is needed at all).

The way to do that is to make the property *private*, and provide getters and setters, or simulate property accessors using the magic `__get` and `__set` methods (and `@property` annotations for use by IDEs). Then you can store a map of which properties have been written to outside of your initialisation code.

A simple and probably buggy implementation to show the general idea:

```php
/**
 * This doc-block will be read by IDEs and provide auto-complete
 * @property int|null $id
 * @property string|null $name
 */
class Test {
    private ?int $id = null;
    private ?string $name = null;

    private array $updatedFields = [];

    /**
     * @internal Only to be called by the ORM
     */
    public function construct(?int $id, ?string $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __get(string $property) {
        if ( property_exists($property, $this) ) {
             return $this->$property;
        }
        else {
             throw new LogicError("No such property '$property'");
        }
    }

    public function __set(string $property, $newValue) {
        if ( property_exists($property, $this) ) {
             $this->$property = $newValue;
             $this->updatedFields[ $property ] = true;
        }
        else {
             throw new LogicError("No such property '$property'");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Standard meaning of isset() for external code 
     */
    public function __isset(string $property) {
        if ( property_exists($property, $this) ) {
             return isset($this->$property);
        }
        else {
             throw new LogicError("No such property '$property'");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Special function for ORM code to determine which fields have changed
     */
    public function hasBeenWritten(string $property): bool {
        if ( property_exists($property, $this) ) {
             return $this->updatedFields[ $property ] ?? false;
        }
        else {
             throw new LogicError("No such property '$property'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is with this approach is that I either write all of my setter and getter function manually for all fields of a table, or if I am using magic methods, I won't have any intellisense support:| but based on what I've researched since asking my question, I think it seems that there is no other way of achieving this in PHP, which is a shame...:( an alternative would be to write a class builder, but as this is a small project I don't think that the time it takes will warrant it, and we are also too late in the dev stage to interchange our custom ORM with something more robust:|

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the docblock on the top of your code. Interesting, I didn't know that it will work this way. I think we are getting to a solution to my problem, thanks! I will accept this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

In case of objects you might want to use [property_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php).

```php
<?php
class Test {
    public $definedButNotSet;
}

$test = new Test();

var_dump(property_exists($test, 'definedButNotSet')); // bool(true)
```

Comment: that's not the problem there. in your case, you are talking about an undefined and unset variable. What I am talking about are object variables that are "defined" (I need to define them, so my intellisense kicks in), but not set.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai It is still similar. I will update my answer.

Comment: what am I trying to diferentiate between is, that the `$definedButNotSet` variable was changed in any way during the runtime. if it was only `defined` but not set to any value (inclusive the `null` value), then I would want to do something with it, otherwise, I would like to do something else with it.

Comment: You will need to do something special, for example override the `__get()` magic method, and keep track of this specific property. When initializing `Test`, the property `definedButNotSet` automatically has a value of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I refer to this as *null switching* and predicate it on an internal property map. For instance:

```
class Test {
    public $define; // null
    public $redefine; // null

    public function define(?bool $something = null): ?bool {
        return $this->define = $this->define ?? $something;
    }

    public function redefine(?bool $something = null): ?bool {
        return $this->redefine = $something ?? $this->redefine;
    }
}

$test = function(?bool $value) {
    var_export($value ?? 'Not set!' ?: 'False!');
    echo PHP_EOL;
};

$foo = new Test();

$test($foo->define());
$test($foo->define(true));
$test($foo->define());
$test($foo->define(false));
$test($foo->define());

$test($foo->redefine());
$test($foo->redefine(true));
$test($foo->redefine());
$test($foo->redefine(false));
$test($foo->redefine());
```

https://3v4l.org/PFXqi